# Texture is suddendly white

Tags: texturing

I dont know what I did but suddendly my green tree branch is white, can someone help me and tell me how to fix it? Im pretty new to blender -
link to the blender file: https://www83.zippyshare.com/v/kuqVBUio/file.html

Comment: file is not downloadable: 403 Forbidden

Comment: just tried it and it works, maybe you have to reload the page?

Comment: I uploaded it to 1fichier.com if the problem persists https://1fichier.com/?rtuae83zc8i7gsf3w7fj

Comment: the texture for the tree branch was taken from https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1cwIwnZcvxDhox2j9p7k6pGTVHMY_1hDx

Comment: Hello, please [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/170439/edit) your question and images to your question, you should use [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) to upload .blend files here as well, and please include only necessary elements, and do pack textures in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect Color information to Diffuse node Color socket :)

[image]

Comment: thank you so much :)